# How can I pass REDIS_URI for NestJS cache manager?

Tags: heroku, caching, redis, nestjs

In the official documentation this is the correct way to use the cache manager with Redis:

```
import * as redisStore from 'cache-manager-redis-store';
import { CacheModule, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';

@Module({
  imports: [
    CacheModule.register({
      store: redisStore,
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 6379,
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Source: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/caching#different-stores

However, I did not find any documentation on how to pass Redis instance data using REDIS_URI. I need to use it with Heroku and I believe this is a common use case.

Comment: looks like you have already found that limitation in `cache-manager-redis-store` package :p https://github.com/dabroek/node-cache-manager-redis-store/pull/19#issuecomment-817486038

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT:

now they are type-safe: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/pull/8592

---

I've exploring a bit about how the redis client is instantiated. Due to [this line](https://github.com/dabroek/node-cache-manager-redis-store/blob/b34ede681fd17638a940ae889f75e5079d971997/index.js#L4) I *think* that the options that you've passed to `CacheModule.register` will be forwarded to [`Redis#createClient`](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis#rediscreateclient) (from `redis` package). Therefore, you can pass the URI like:

```js
CacheModule.register({
  store: redisStore,
  url: 'redis://localhost:6379'
})
```

try this and let me know if it works.

---

edit:

Explaining how I got that:

Taking `{ store: redisStore, url: '...' }` as `options`.

1. [Here in `CacheModule.register`](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/3e2fc27d62d665913639aa238b02ef1f87255bcc/packages/common/cache/cache.module.ts#L33) I found that your `options` will live under `CACHE_MODULE_OPTIONS` token (as a Nest *provider*)
2. Then I search for places in where this token will be used. Then I found [here](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/0055eb97cf77229427df8fca573797a03dae6979/packages/common/cache/cache.providers.ts#L21) that those `options` were passed to `cacheManager.caching`. Where `cacheManager` [is the module `cache-manager`](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/0055eb97cf77229427df8fca573797a03dae6979/packages/common/cache/cache.providers.ts#L17)
3. Looking into to the `cacheManager.caching`'s code [here](https://github.com/BryanDonovan/node-cache-manager/blob/00e688c5b1de6e88446f6bc800b04094b2c7ebba/lib/caching.js#L17), you'll see that your `options` is now their `args` parameter
4. Since `options.store` (`redisStore`) is the module exported by [`cache-manager-redis-store`](https://github.com/dabroek/node-cache-manager-redis-store/blob/b34ede681fd17638a940ae889f75e5079d971997/index.js#L214) package, [`args.store.create`](https://github.com/BryanDonovan/node-cache-manager/blob/00e688c5b1de6e88446f6bc800b04094b2c7ebba/lib/caching.js#L22) method is the same function as in [`redisStore.create`](https://github.com/dabroek/node-cache-manager-redis-store/blob/b34ede681fd17638a940ae889f75e5079d971997/index.js#L211)
5. Thus `args.store.create(args)` is the same as doing `redisStore.create(options)` which, in the end, will call [`Redis.createClient passing this options`](https://github.com/dabroek/node-cache-manager-redis-store/blob/b34ede681fd17638a940ae889f75e5079d971997/index.js#L3-L4)

Comment: Nice, this solves it for me.